# Can't make 2 classes work in one activity?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I have `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        System.out.println("MainActivity talking here"); //this works
    }
}
```

And, `NewActivity`:

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        System.out.println("NewActivity talking here"); //this doesn't work!
    }
}
```

Why doesn't `System.out.println("NewActivity talking here");` work?

Comment: Because `NewActivity` isn't running.

Comment: How do you start `NewActivity`?

Comment: @QBrute I don't think it starts, I just have it there. I want it to start the same way `MainActivity` does.

Comment: @JonathanDoe Only 1 activity runs at a time.  If you want a second activity to run, you need to launch it.  At which point the original activity is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely you are starting the wrong activity. If you don't explicitly have code doing this, then it is in your `manifest`. There is an activity tag with an intent filter categorized as `LAUNCHER`. (This was auto generated for you when you created your project). The activity with this filter will be the activity that starts on launch.

To start another activity, declare it in your manifest and use an intent. These are all simple things to do that you can learn with a quick google search.

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about Java classes. The Java class `MainActivity` automatically starts when `activity_main` opens. But, the class `NewActivity` does not start. How can I make it start also?

Comment: My answer still stands -- you need to declare it in your manifest and start it via Intent: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I don't want to start another activity though. I only have 1 activity.

Comment: I have 1 activity and 2 classes to control that activity.

Comment: Can you please give an example to achieve that?

Comment: You have two Activity classes. Each class will be its own. You cannot use two activities to control one

Comment: The reason for this is that I want to avoid having one **huge** MainActivity class to control an activity. I want to separate into smaller classes. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: This is a much larger question, and fortunate for you, is answered countless times on the web. Maybe take a look at [this StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) for some strategies or [Android Sample Projects](https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html) for some examples